# Regex in Notepad++for sections from latex to markdown

Tags: regex, latex, markdown, notepad++

I have many tex files containing something like `\chapter{ccc}`, `\section{sss}`, etc. I want to change them to markdown format like `# ccc`, `## sss`, etc.; my minimal demo is as follows:

```
\chapter{math}

mmm

\section{opt}

ooo

\section{prob}

ppp

\section{stat}

sss

\subsection{biostat}

bbb

\chapter{phys}

yyy

\chapter{chem}

ccc
```

Take `section` for example, I tried

```
Find: \\section(\{.*?\})
Replace: ## $1
```

while the braces `{}` are still there. How can solve this problem? Or are there any more efficient ways can get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the match group from outside `(\{.*?\})` to inside the curly braces `\{(.*?)\}`:

```
Find: \\section\{(.*?)\}
Replace: ## $1
```

Now the the match group `$1` only contain the text `opt`, `prob`, etc.. inside the curly braces. The results:

```
\chapter{math}

mmm

## opt

ooo

## prob

ppp

## stat

sss

\subsection{biostat}

bbb

\chapter{phys}

yyy

\chapter{chem}

ccc
```

Comment: Great, it works well! @dinhit